# ASP.NET Reporting - Do any tools allow the generation of a composite report from parts of other reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, telerik, devexpress, reporting

Let's say I have 10 reports, each of which contain 1 or more tables and charts.
I want to allow a user to select a bar chart from report 1, a grid and pie chart from report 2, a grid from report 3 etc to create a composite report.

I think I have a solution in **Telerik** whereby I combine multiple reports together, as sub-reports, and hide all elements (tables, charts) except the ones that the user wants to include. If all elements are placed inside min-sized panels then white space should disappear as elements are hidden. I've done a quick test using this method and it appears to work.

My question is, is this the best way to approach the requirment? Are there better approaches with other tools such as **Crystal Reports**, **ActiveReports** and **DevExpress**?

Answer (score 3):

Jules

Are you trying to combine these report at run time?  In ActiveReports, these 3 reports can be run separately and then all the three of them can be combined to create one report document or individual pages from these can be combined together to create another report document.  This document can then be viewed in any of the viewers, printed or exported to pdf and excel and such.

At design time, it is doable but is not worth it.  Will need some code to make sure that the layout is first created correctly based on user selection of certain kind of report and then you will have to make sure that correct data is getting fed prior to running the report.